# Align items to bottom of container without tables?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create a sort of slider/carousel and since the items have different heights, i want to align them to the bottom of the container. As of now, this is done using tables, but of course since i want my thing to also be responsive i can't allow tables. My first thought was using absolute positioning but that obviously doesn't work since the elements do need to occupy a space after all. What do you suggest?

the HTML :

```
<div class="categories-wheel">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="categories-wheel__arrow categories-wheel__arrow--left">
                <span class="middle-vertical-align-helper"></span><!--
                @fix: no whitespace allowed between span and i tags
                --><i class="icon icon-thin-chevron-left"></i>
            </div>


            <div class="categories-wheel__arrow categories-wheel__arrow--right">
                <span class="middle-vertical-align-helper"></span><!--
                @fix: no whitespace allowed between span and i tags
                --><i class="icon icon-thin-chevron-right"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="categories-wheel__entries">

                <div class="categories-wheel__entries__entry">
                    <img class="categories-wheel__entries__entry__image" src="/resources/images/products/baterie_categorie_green.png" alt="" />
                    <span class="categories-wheel__entries__entry__name"> Green </span>
                </div>

                <div class="categories-wheel__entries__entry">
                    <img class="categories-wheel__entries__entry__image" src="/resources/images/products/baterie_categorie_agm.png" alt="" />
                    <span class="categories-wheel__entries__entry__name"> AGM </span>
                </div>

                <div class="categories-wheel__entries__entry">
                    <img class="categories-wheel__entries__entry__image" src="/resources/images/products/baterie_categorie_forte.png" alt="" />
                    <span class="categories-wheel__entries__entry__name"> Forte </span>
                </div>

                <div class="categories-wheel__entries__entry">
                    <img class="categories-wheel__entries__entry__image" src="/resources/images/products/baterie_categorie_terra.png" alt="" />
                    <span class="categories-wheel__entries__entry__name"> Terra </span>
                </div>

                <div class="categories-wheel__entries__entry">
                    <img class="categories-wheel__entries__entry__image" src="/resources/images/products/baterie_categorie_moto.png" alt="" />
                    <span class="categories-wheel__entries__entry__name"> RBX </span>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the CSS:

```
/*
 * CATEGORIES WHEEL
 * ============================================== */

.categories-wheel {
    height                      : 270px;
    padding                     : 30px 10px;
    background                  : #ffffff;
    text-align                  : center;
}

.categories-wheel__arrow {
    display                     : inline-block;
    height                      : 100%;
    padding                     : 0 10px;
    font-size                   : 6em;
    color                       : #cccccc;
    line-height                 : 240px;
}

.categories-wheel__arrow:hover {
    cursor                      : pointer;
    color                       : #b1b1b1; 
}

.categories-wheel__arrow--left {
    float                       : left;
}

.categories-wheel__arrow--right {
    float                       : right;
}

.categories-wheel__entries {
    display                     : table;
    margin                      : 0 auto;
}

.categories-wheel__entries__entry {
    display                     : table-cell;
    vertical-align              : bottom;
    padding                     : 0 10px;
}

.categories-wheel__entries__entry:hover {
    cursor                      : pointer;
}

.categories-wheel__entries__entry:hover .categories-wheel__entries__entry__name {
    color                       : #ed161c;
}

.categories-wheel__entries__entry:hover .categories-wheel__entries__entry__image {
    animation                   : zoomInOut 0.2s ease;
}


.categories-wheel__entries__entry__name {
    display                     : block;
    width                       : 100%;
    margin-top                  : 10px;
    text-align                  : center;
    font-size                   : 2em;
    font-weight                 : 500;

    transition                  : color 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition          : color 0.5s ease;
}
```

and how the situation looks like as of now: http://puu.sh/ndu0y/baf72d9132.jpg

Comment: Take a look to flex-box https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Is vertical-align:bottom not working for you?

Comment: You need to post all relevant CSS if you want a solution that doesn't break your current functionality. What does `zoomInOut` animation do? What properties does it change? Are you using any libraries? Link them until your snippet is a [mcve] of your current behaviour.

Comment: @JamiePaterson `vertical-align` doesn't work on `display:table` elements.

Comment: @Andrei The question states they will not use tables because they want it to be made easily responsive! - even tough you can actually make tables respond though if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
.parent {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
.child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-c-150-100-9.jpg" alt="" /><span>Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/city-h-c-100-200-3.jpg" alt="" /><span>Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/sports-h-c-50-100-1.jpg" alt="" /><span>Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/city-h-c-100-200-3.jpg" alt="" /><span>Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/city-h-c-100-200-3.jpg" alt="" /><span>Title</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/rxgYpV)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a bootstrap responsive panel, like this...
https://goo.gl/hRXG5M
Tell me if you want something different done, as I can help. What sort of solution do you want?

PS: you need to import the relevant scripts for this solution:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @AndreiGheorghiu said you should add a Minimal complete example to have an accurate answer.
I would use vertical-align:bottom on your categories-wheel__entries with a height of 100%, so your div will take the full height of his container and the images will be at the bottom.